# M-matrix and discrete maximum principle

Tags: linear-algebra, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, numerical-calculus

We say that $A\in M(n,n)$ is an $M$-matrix if it can be written as $A= \alpha I_n -B$, where $B\geq 0$ (inequalities taken componentwise).

I want to prove the following property of $M$-matrices:

**Proposition.** Let $A$ be an irreducible, non singular $n\times n$ $M$-matrix. Then it holds the Discrete Maximum Principle, i.e. if we have $y\in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $Ay\geq 0$, then $\max\{y_1,y_n\}=\max_i\{y_i\}$

I know that an irreducible $M$-matrix $A$ is non singular and $A^{-1}>0$ iff $\alpha > \rho(B)$ (where $\rho$ is the spectral radius), iff there exists $v\in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $v>0$ and $Av \geq 0$, $Av \neq 0$.

Any help would be really appreciated!

*Edit* 
In the solutions of some tests about the finite difference method for discretization of pdes my professor wrote that for an M-matrix the discrete maximum principle holds (which is false, as proven in the answer below), *hence* the system is stable (i.e. the norm of the inverse of the matrix of the linear system is uniformly bounded from above (supremum norm)). 
How can I prove that discrete maximum principle implies stability?
(If it is true; at this point I am not sure of anything!).

Comment: What is the question at the end? Also, this is a bit strange formulation of the DMP. Does it assume a particular structure of the algebraic problem?